# Можно ли бэкапить MySQL, тупо копируя каталог с БД?

Tags: mysql, резервное-копирование, mariadb

Ситуация такова: есть мастер-сервер MySQL (ну или MariaDB, если быть точным), есть реплика. Каждую ночь mysqld с репликой отключается на время, и папочка с БД реплики (условная `/var/lib/mysql`) пихается в архив с бэкапом, после чего mysqld включается обратно.

Такие дела у меня с 2014 года (делалось по принципу «потом разберусь», и это «потом» должно когда-то уже наступить :). Я периодически пробую выкатывать старые бэкапы — работает. *Пока* работает. Так как такое копирование не является «легальной» формой создания бэкапа (это всё-таки не mysqldump и не xtrabackup какие-нибудь), у меня нет полной уверенности в его надёжности.

Если кто достаточно хорошо знает, как работает MySQL/MariaDB, расскажите, есть ли какие-нибудь подводные камни, которые могут вылезти у таких бэкапов в будущем? Или, если не забывать запускать `mysql_upgrade`, всё будет хорошо? Или, может, есть какие-то зависимости от ОС, системных библиотек или параметров конфигурации, которые могут случайно сломать такой бэкап?

Comment: нежелательно. лучше использовать mysqldump.

Comment: @Сергей он непозволительно медленный, восстановление 12-гиговой базы занимает около суток

Comment: восстановление на чем? железо? я восстанавливал базу так для примера весом 10гб, самая большая таблица там 110к сторок, времени это заняло мин 7. Железо 4 ядра 3.4гц ссд 8гб рам

Comment: @Сергей таблица в десяток миллионов строк на хдд 2.7ггц 12гб рам восстанавливалась 4 часа

Comment: ну если вы в будущем не собираетесь переходить на другую версию субд и нет каких-то специфичных настроек, триггеров итд, то пользуйтесь копиркой, это нормально. Хотя и не факт, что могут возникнуть проблемы на другой субд, так как опыт уже был (mysql5.5 - 5.7)

Comment: Конечно можно, дампить то, что нагенерил mysqldump очень медленно, на настоящих живых проектах. Перед снапшотом не обязательно "выключать" субд, достаточно лочить через `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`. Если нужно развернуть локальную копию БД - конечно проще скопировать, но только если список БД одинаковый: разделить и объединить с InnoDB (и настройками по дефолту) не выйдет.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Просто копировать каталог базы нельзя. Но вы-то его копируете не просто, а остановив базу.

> Так как такое копирование не является «легальной» формой создания бэкапа

[Является раз](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-backup.html) - `Cold Backups`. [Является два.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-methods.html) - `Making Backups Using a File System Snapshot`.

Копирования каталога и файлов конфигурации базы **при остановленной базе** является допустимым вариантом. Но, как это водится с бекапами - в любом случае полезно регулярно проверять, что вы можете восстановиться из бекапа.

Для бекапа `innodb` таблиц указана рекомендация останавливать СУБД как `clean shutdown`, т.е. с указанием

```
mysql -u root -p --execute="SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown=0"
# выключить базу
# убедиться, что она действительно выключилась
# скопировать datadir и конфиги
# запустить базу вновь
```

Восстанавливать из физического бекапа разумеется надо на ту же major-версию, что и использовалась перед снятие бекапа и не ниже такой же минорной. Так как для major обновления версии базы существуют [отдельные инструкции](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html). Хотя и весьма близкие по смыслу инструкции, но не надо совмещать апгрейд системы и восстановление после аварии.

Comment: `на ту же major-версию` кстати переносили так вот, копипастом, с mysql 5.5 на MariaDB 10.2 - и нормально, всё взлетело! И там не одна БД была, а несколько, объёмом 10Gb :)

Answer (score 3):

Если вы останавливаете БД с репликой, то, при прочих равных, вы получаете целостную копию базы. Никаких проблем быть не должно.

Проблемы могут быть если вы думаете, что остановили БД с репликой, а на самом деле что-то пошло не так и реплика всё ещё работает. Стоит проверять что в самом деле никакой процесс MySQL не занимает файлы БД перед копированием.

Такая ситуация может возникнуть потому что скрипты, выключающие БД, ждут выключения лишь фиксированное время. Если за это время MySQL не выключится, то скрипты заверша­тся с ошибкой. Если эту ошибку не проверять в скрипте (например, через `set -e`), то ваша программа будет копировать файлы БД, которые изменяются по ходу дела. Естественно, в такой копии БД может быть всё, что угодно.

Answer (score 0):

Случайно нашел данный вопрос и решил дополнить его вариантом ответа с **"горячим бэкапом"**.

Возможно он не отвечает на сформулированный вопрос, но он может помочь найти лучшее решение для резервного копирования и восстановления, о котором ищущий еще не знает.

Компания Percona выпускает бесплатный [продукт `Percona XtraBackup`](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup#:%7E:text=The%20Percona%20XtraBackup%20tools%20provide,for%20MySQL%20and%20MySQL%C2%AE.), который умеет делать быстрый, неблокирующий, бинарный и сжатый бэкап **работающей** БД (`MySQL`, `MariaDB`, `XtraDB` и другие с поддержкой `InnoDB`, `XtraDB`, and `MyISAM` движков):

> The Percona XtraBackup tools provide a method of performing a hot
> backup of your MySQL data while the system is running. Percona
> XtraBackup is a free, online, open source, complete database backups
> solution for all versions of Percona Server for MySQL and MySQL®.
> Percona XtraBackup performs online non-blocking, tightly compressed,
> highly secure full backups on transactional systems so that
> applications remain fully available during planned maintenance
> windows.

[XtraBackup также поддерживает создание резервных копий с работающих реплик](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/innobackupex/replication_ibk.html) - для этого существуют опции `--slave-info` и `--safe-slave-backup`.

Comment: удалять ответ не буду, т.к. нахожу его полезным ;)