# Как сделать грамотно mysqldump

Tags: mysql, резервное-копирование

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть сервер, на котором highload базa mysql. Насколько я знаю, что бы создался корректный бекап, который можно будет восстановить без проблем, нужно хотя бы блокировать таблицы на запись.

Собственно, если я заблокирую запись таблицам и в этот момент прилетит запрос на запись, как поведет себя база?

После разблокировки будут ли внесены записи, которые не внеслись, или они будут безрезультатно утеряны?

Думал делать бекапы таким образом. Подправьте, пожалуйста, как лучше.

```
mysqldump --triggers --routines --events --skip-add-locks user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --databases $db  > $OUTPUT/$db.sql;
```

Вычитал про Percona XtraBackup и InnDB HOT Backup.

Так всё же. Как лучше безопасно создавать бекап?

Comment: Безопасно - через реплику :)

Comment: Всё же идёт речь о консольном бекапировании. Несколько причин есть почему не подходит репликация. И вообще, кривые руки никто не отменял: если вдруг на продакшине будет какой-то факап, то оно фактически моментально уйдет на слейв, не успеешь даже очнуться...

Comment: Ну так для того бэкапы и делают, чтобы факапы можно было откатить. Отключаете репликацию, запускаете mysqldump на реплике, включаете репликацию

Comment: И вообще с репликой можно делать бэкапы, тупо копируя папку mysql куда-нибудь :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/753340 Я такие бэкапы с реплики уже три года коллекционирую, спасли от двух факапов)

Comment: А если из консоли, то, всё таки, как это максимально грамотно сделать?    если я заблокирую запись таблицам и в этот момент прилетит запрос на запись, как поведет себя база?

После разблокировки будут ли внесены записи, которые не внеслись, или они будут безрезультатно утеряны?

Comment: Если таблица заблокирована, то insert/update будет просто ждать и не вернет управление клиенту который его вызвал, до тех пор пока блокировка не снимется. Тут уже вопросы что за приложение, на сколько страшно, что клиент будет ждать. Не истекут ли у клиента какие нибудь таймауты и не крашнится ли он от этого

Comment: mysqldump -u USER -p --single-transaction --quick --all-databases  > OUTPUT.sql   => примерно так можно бекапить?

Answer (score 1):

как по мне лучше не использовать mysqldump лучше посмотрите в сторону [Percona XtraBackup for MySQL Databases](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup). А так лучше конечно же настроить Mysql Slave и делать бекапы на нем. И Вы спокойно можете сделать отставания mysql-slave от mysql-master например на 1 час или более и в случае какого либо краша на мастере вы у вас будет время чтобы остановить слейв вовремя.

Comment: Я несколько раз уже посматривал на эту персону. Возможно, все-таки, надо ее потестить на тестовом сервере...

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от размера базы, если он небольшой, то дамп сделается очень быстро (для примера, дамп базы размером 250 Мб делается у меня за 2-3 секунды (сервер - IntelXeon 8x 6132 2.6 ГГц, ОЗУ - 12 Гб, загружен на 5-10%).
К тому же вы можете поставить процесс создания дампа в крон и запланировать его в то время, когда пользователи вашего сайта наименее активно его посещают, например, в 2-3 часа ночи.

Если в процессе создания дампа прилетит запрос, то он просто "встанет в очередь", так как база во время дампа блокируется. Если он простоит в очереди долго и отвалится (какой указан тайм-аут в настройках MySQL?), то пользователь об этом или узнает или нет - смотря как настроена ваша система (сайт). В худшем случае ему придется просто обновить страницу или отправить запрос заново.